# You never know what you will find when

Tags: word

While digging through his old credit card bills,

> This former

> Bean counter

> Discovered a special tax paid

> On a utility charge

What word is that?

Comment: Those don't seem like *spoilers* - why are they hidden? Is there a way to solve this puzzle with only the visible text?

Comment: @bobble Looks like they are hidden to clue the answer based on how the solver must interact with the puzzle.

Answer (score 3):

I think the concealed word is:

> **EXCAVATION**

*This former*

> 'former' = **EX**

*Bean counter*

> 'Bean counter' = **CA** (Chartered Accountant)

*Discovered a special tax paid*

> 'a special tax' = **[VAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value-added_tax)**

*On a utility charge*

> 'charge' = **[ION](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion)** (i.e. a *charged* particle, in Physics)
>
>  <sup>Note here also the link between 'utility' and 'electric' (hence, electric charge) - a deliberate choice of words from the OP to serve as an additional hint...</sup>

This would also explain:

> the use of the synonym 'DIGGING' in the first line, and the idea inherent in the title that if you are *excavating* something, you have no idea what you will find beneath the surface until you turn it up!

Comment: Rirelguvat evtug. Nyfb V fahpx va "hgvyvgl" gurer gb zrna "ryrpgevpvgl" punetr. Whfg n fznyy pyhr.